# Joomla remove scripts and css loaded by extensions

Tags: scripting, joomla2.5

Using Joomla 2.5 and I have a dual instance of jquery running on one of my pages that I would like to get rid of.  I tried using,

```
$document->getHeadData();
```

to no avail.  The array does not contain the js files I need to unset.  So what is my best option to find the js file and unload it?  It seems to be getting loaded later in the page rendering process and then repopulating the head data.  I am using a yoo theme template with some other extensions loaded.

I would like to avoid hard coding the template/extension files if possible since that would unload it on every page and I only want to unload it for one page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php 
         //get the array containing all the script declarations
         $document = JFactory::getDocument(); 
         $headData = $document->getHeadData();
         $scripts = $headData['scripts'];


         unset($scripts['/media/system/js/mootools-core.js']);
         unset($scripts['/media/system/js/mootools-more.js']);
         $headData['scripts'] = $scripts;
         $document->setHeadData($headData);
?>
```

**Or**

```
<?php unset($this->_scripts['/media/system/js/mootools-core.js']); ?>
```

then simply use `$document->addScript()` for adding new `js` files.

hope its works..